# How much impact can an SD card have in battery life?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, sd-card, battery-life

I have a samsung tablet and since I bought the sd card I notice imapact on the battery.

Unfortunatly I installed Android 5 by the same time (thatś why I bought the card), so its unclear if its the card or the OS change.

I have read that Android 5 has a poorer performance in terms of battery life, but I even givin that as a fact  I think the tablet is using too much energy.

Comment: How did you conclude that SD card is causing the battery drain? Give us the battery statistics (screenshots) from Settings -> Battery.

Comment: I dont know.  I am just asking if this can be a reason. The 2 things that changed since I started noticing this was the OS and the card.  The OS is a strong candidate, but I was wondering about the card also.

Comment: If 2 things have changed, then eliminate the change of 1 thing and watch your battery. So you can either uninstall Android 5 and return back to 4.x or remove the SD card. The latter would be easier I think.

Comment: @Alex.S thatś a good idea in theory. In practice I use my tablet daily for work and I was not able to do that yet. Specially because I have most of the apps I need for work there. It seemed a good idea to ask for facts.

Comment: In my case i saw a significant difference in battery life with and without an sd card, i tested it on my samusng tab 4 and battery life is better when the card is out as compared when its in.

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible for the SD card driver to be terrible and to spin uselessly wasting battery, but far from typical.  Accessing the SD card shouldn't really use any more battery than accessing any other kind of storage.